# Jenkins UI - 'Environment Variables' Button Missing

Tags: jenkins

I recently started a new job and they use Jenkins (which I have used before).

I am used to seeing an Environment Variables button when you look at a build in the UI, however it appears to be missing.

Does anyone know how I can get that button to appear?

Environment variables are being set as I can do a `printenv | sort` and see all the parameters that are being set and the default Jenkins environment variables.

I haven't been able to find anything online that is similar to this issue.

**Current Jenkins Version**: `2.190.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Environment Variables** link is available in Freestyle projects. If yours is a Pipeline project, you will not see it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, that is what I assumed but was hoping for it not to be the case.

Comment: You can still use `printenv` in your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'Environment Variables' button - which is only available for **freestyle** jobs (e.g. https:// jenkins-url/job/my-freestyle-job/5/injectedEnvVars) - has disappeared from the builds sidebar, then go to https://jenkins-url/configureSecurity and **uncheck** "Enable permissions" under Environment Injector Plugin:

[image]

Comment: "Me too" and//or link only answers are not accepted on SO and will probably be deleted. At the very least, include a summary of what we can find in the link your provide. Thank you. Moreover, this rather looks like a comment. You will be able to comment on any post once you get enough reputation. You should appropriately contribute to the site (edit, correct question/answers, etc...) to gain some.